# How can I use getElementById or querySelectorAll for an infinite number of IDs? (creating toggle buttons to show/hide divs)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

Javascript noob here, as you can probably tell, and was wondering if anyone could help me clean this up. Trying to avoid Jquery, please.

**It’s pretty basic:** There’s a toggle button, a section of content, and a close button within that section of content. The content is hidden by default, but when the toggle button is clicked, the content becomes visible and the user gets auto-scrolled to it. When the close button is clicked, the section of content disappears and the user is auto-scrolled back up to the main section with all the toggle buttons.

This should be repeated for individual sections of content, with each unique content section associated with its corresponding toggle button.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bythrees/mw5nh1cd/51/

*This works as intended but is there a way to clean up the Javascript so that if more than 2 sections of content are desired, it will happen automatically, without having to add another section — Toggle 3, Toggle 4, Toggle 5, and so on — to the JS? I was looking into querySelectorAll (I don't HAVE to be using IDs, can easily use classes) and map but don’t know how to make it work.*

Here's the code I'm using. It just seems dumb if I have to repeat all of that for each Toggle, changing the numbers for each one.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle-1');
  const toggleContent1 = document.getElementById('toggle-content-1');
  const closeContent1 = document.getElementById('close-toggle-1');

  const toggle2 = document.getElementById('toggle-2');
  const toggleContent2 = document.getElementById('toggle-content-2');
  const closeContent2 = document.getElementById('close-toggle-2');

  // Toggle 1

  if (toggle1) {
    toggle1.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggleContent1.classList.toggle('show');
    });

    closeContent1.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggleContent1.classList.remove('show');
    });
  }

  // Toggle 2

  if (toggle2) {
    toggle2.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggleContent2.classList.toggle('show');
    });

    closeContent2.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggleContent2.classList.remove('show');
    });
  }

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: uses classes so you don't need unique IDs. if you first locate a wrapping tag, you can search for children of the outer tag by class, eg: `var div = byid("blah"); div.querySelector(".toggle-content").addEventLi....`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j17yq6gh/  is a stripped down but quantity expandable example.  you should also look into the summary/details html tag, it works w/o javascript, and you can style it with css to not have the silly arrow. You can also easily open/close them with a link/button; all you do is toggle the _open_ attrib on the details tag.